# Number Theory system of congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Find an integer $x$ such that $-2310\leq x\leq 2310$ and

$x \equiv 1   $ (mod 21)
$x \equiv 2   $ (mod 20)
$x \equiv 3   $ (mod 11)

I think I have a solution but was is confusing me is that $x$ has to be $-2310\leq x\leq 2310$. So, it's only saying that $x$ has to lie between those bounds and my modulus does not. My work is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I confirm that $x=-1658$ is the only solution.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right! Your work shows that there exist an infinite number of x that satisfy your system of congruences, but only one of them lies in the indicated range.